# Find best value for size of the table in hashing

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, hash-tables

> Given a set of keys $\{i^2|0\leq i\leq 100\}$, and a hash table such that
> collision resolve by chaining. Our hash function is  $ k \mod m$ .
>
> What is option is best for $m$ to decrease our search for items in hash table and why?
>
> a.7
>
> b.9
>
> c.11
>
> d.12

I think c is the best choice, but i can't prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all rather bad, since you cannot avoid having at least nine keys having the same hash value, independent of the key.

For your particular problem, calculate the possible values of i^2 modulo 7, 9, 11, 12. For example i^2 modulo 7 is 0, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1. I^2 modulo 12 = 0, 1, 4, 9, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 9, 4, 1. In each case, count how often each hash value appears (12: five 4s, four 1s, two 9s, one 0) and how many collisions you can expect (5^2+4^2+2^2+1^2)/144 = 46 / 144 = pretty bad.

I=11 should give you 21/121 collisions on average; still pretty bad but the best of the lot. You better check the calculations.

You have the problem that none of these hash functions distributes your keys remotely evenly. Something like (k * 1.3748538) mod c will destroy the mathematical relationship and gives much better results.